# How to add random sleep time in Tkinter using after()

Tags: python, tkinter

i searched a lot for this problem but i couldnt find any,
problem is:
with after(), i have to use a fixed number as time, but outside of tkinter i can use a take a number from random range and put it in time.sleep(), this is important for me to have a random time sleep. is the any way to use with tkinter?

example in python:

```
time.sleep(random.randrange(120, 480))
```

which tkinter will hangs out with that.
example in tkinter:

```
root.after(1000, my_function)
```

which is fixed on 1000 (for example) and i cant pass an argument or use something like *random.randrange()* inside it.

Comment: Why can't you use `random.randrange`? There's nothing about `after` that would prevent that. Have you tried?

Comment: yes it worked, problem was using after inside while loop which causes not responding, thanks to answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `random` (or any function that returns a positive integer) inside `after` method doesn't seem to be a problem. The below works well

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

def random_timer():
    global time 
    label['text']=time
    time+=1
    root.after(random.randint(100,1000),random_timer)

root=Tk()

label=Label(root)
label.pack()

time=0
random_timer()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it worked, i had another problem: having a while loop in a function which makes problem tkinter working, so i designed to rerun function using root.after() and it worked. thanks for help :X